# android contact list shortcut

Tags: android, list, contacts

I am trying to write application but I have problem. I want call android application with all contacts by pressing button in my app. I have no idea how to do it. I am looking on google, but no one solution in there sort it out my problem. Pls if any one could give me some idea where or how should I do it.

Comment: Please mention what have to tried so far...

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you're question, you need reed this http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html article. This article will give you understanding how to fetch contact lists.